# Editing the code for a recorded Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new to using macros and code, and am running into a small problem. I have a sheet where I update values along a row. Since these updates are part of a process, I want excel to record my row as a sort of history in next sheet in my workbook. I recorded a macro where when I press cntrl+r, it copies the first row from my data sheet, inserts a row onto the history page, and then copies the data onto that new row. THe only problem I that my data sheet will have multiple rows of data, and I would like the macro to copy my selected row, not just the first row everytime. I have put the code below.

Thank you!

```
Sub RecordTracker()
RecordTracker Macro
Records the updated row as a history row in Documentation Sheet
Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r

    Sheets("Documentation").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Tracker").Select
    Range("A3:S3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Documentation").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Sorry if my formatting of the code is a little off. First post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Will Insert a new Row on sheet `Documentation` from (`A2`)
2. Copy the row you have selected (from sheet `Tracker`, Range `A:S`)
3. Paste values onto `Documentation` `A2` (which is your newly created row)

This will need to be pasted in VBE on your sheet `Tracker` to execute

Notice that your code can be greatly reduced (as far as lines go) by avoiding the `.Select` method. You can find some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

```
Sub StoreChanges()

    Sheets("Documentation").Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Tracker").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "S")).Copy
    Sheets("Documentation").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I right click on Documentation, show code, and paste there?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Should I be deleting what I have on VBE for the Tracker sheet? If so, how to I get this process to run? Thank you!

Comment: I meant how to add a shortcut to run the macro as I will be having multiple people using the sheet, but I can definitely figure that out! :)

Unfortunately, when I run the macro I run into an error that reads: 400

Comment: Ah no worries! Works like a charm now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before your first `.Select`:

```
r = ActiveCell.Row
```

then you want to change this line:

```
Range("A3:S3").Select
```

to this:

```
Range("A" & Cstr(r) & ":S" & Cstr(r)).Select
```

I think that that should do it.

---

NOTE:  Using `.Select` is slow and has some other reliability/interaction problems, so we usually advise against it.  However, it's hard to do a true Copy operation without it, so it's probably OK in this case.  *However*, if you don't *really* need a true copy (formats, formulas, et. al.), but only want the value, then there's a better way to do this.

---

Here's a better way, since you only need the data.  I have broken it into individual lines so that you can see how it is done.

```
Sub RecordTracker()
'RecordTracker Macro
'Records the updated row as a history row in Documentation Sheet
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl r

    ' get the worksheet objects
    Dim wsDoc As Worksheet, wsTrak As Worksheet
    Set wsDoc = Sheets("Documentation")
    Set wsTrak = Sheets("Tracker")

    ' get the source (current) row
    Dim r As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row

    'Make the output row
    wsDoc.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '.Range("A2:S2").Select

    ' get the source data
    Dim dat() As Variant
    dat = wsTrak.Range("A" & CStr(r) & ":S" & CStr(r))

    ' set the output range
    Dim outRng As Range
    Set outRng = wsDoc.Range("A2:S2")

    ' copy data to the output range
    outRng = dat
End Sub
```

Comment: I am only looking to copy the values! I definitely do not want to copy the formulas.

Comment: This worked great for me so far. Would you also be able to help me change where the row is inserted on the Documentation page? It is putting it at the top, but I would like to save the top row for titles for tables so I can sort the history.

Comment: @J.Cain where do you want it inserted?

Comment: I would like it to insert a new row at A2 rather than A1, i.e. a new second row.

Comment: @J.Cain Also, are you the J.Cain that I know?

Comment: Okay haha well I hope you find your J. Cain. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in the datasheet (Tracker) you want the selected range/row to be pasted and not just the third row `A3:S3`

> I recorded a macro where when I press cntrl+r,it copies the first row from my data sheet, inserts a row onto the
>   history page, and then copies the data onto that new row

Try removing the `Range("A3:S3").Select` line of code. Now when you select a row in the sheet **Tracker** manually, that row should be used in the code `Selection.Copy`

```
Sheets("Documentation").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Sheets("Tracker").Select
## removed Range("a3:s3").select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Documentation").Select
```

And if you want to add a new row second row onwards, just add `Sheets("Documentation").Rows("2:2").Select` before the code `Selection.Insert`